# Draw polygons, and calculate areas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm looking for a code that allows to draw polygons, with the mouse, and to calculate the surface.
As well as selecting an angle and moving it to transform the shape.
PS: I managed to draw lines between different points and close them to create a polygon.
But I can not select the points to transform the polygons.

My question is: Is there anyone who has already invented this wheel ?

Cordially.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use d3 for this. See this related fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eZQdE/43/

```js
var dragging = false, drawing = false, startPoint;
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('height', 1000)
    .attr('width', 1000);
var points = [], g;
// behaviors
var dragger = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('drag', handleDrag)
    .on('dragend', function(d){
        dragging = false;
    });
svg.on('mouseup', function(){
    if(dragging) return;
    drawing = true;
    startPoint = [d3.mouse(this)[0], d3.mouse(this)[1]];
    if(svg.select('g.drawPoly').empty()) g = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'drawPoly');
    if(d3.event.target.hasAttribute('is-handle')) {
        closePolygon();
        return;
    };
    points.push(d3.mouse(this));
    g.select('polyline').remove();
    var polyline = g.append('polyline').attr('points', points)
                    .style('fill', 'none')
                    .attr('stroke', '#000');
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        g.append('circle')
        .attr('cx', points[i][0])
        .attr('cy', points[i][1])
        .attr('r', 4)
        .attr('fill', 'yellow')
        .attr('stroke', '#000')
        .attr('is-handle', 'true')
        .style({cursor: 'pointer'});
    }
});
function closePolygon() {
    svg.select('g.drawPoly').remove();
    var g = svg.append('g');
    g.append('polygon')
    .attr('points', points)
    .style('fill', getRandomColor());
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var circle = g.selectAll('circles')
        .data([points[i]])
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', points[i][0])
        .attr('cy', points[i][1])
        .attr('r', 4)
        .attr('fill', '#FDBC07')
        .attr('stroke', '#000')
        .attr('is-handle', 'true')
        .style({cursor: 'move'})
        .call(dragger);
    }
    points.splice(0);
    drawing = false;
}
svg.on('mousemove', function() {
    if(!drawing) return;
    var g = d3.select('g.drawPoly');
    g.select('line').remove();
    var line = g.append('line')
                .attr('x1', startPoint[0])
                .attr('y1', startPoint[1])
                .attr('x2', d3.mouse(this)[0] + 2)
                .attr('y2', d3.mouse(this)[1])
                .attr('stroke', '#53DBF3')
                .attr('stroke-width', 1);
})
function handleDrag() {
    if(drawing) return;
    var dragCircle = d3.select(this), newPoints = [], circle;
    dragging = true;
    var poly = d3.select(this.parentNode).select('polygon');
    var circles = d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll('circle');
    dragCircle
    .attr('cx', d3.event.x)
    .attr('cy', d3.event.y);
    for (var i = 0; i < circles[0].length; i++) {
        circle = d3.select(circles[0][i]);
        newPoints.push([circle.attr('cx'), circle.attr('cy')]);
    }
    poly.attr('points', newPoints);
}
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

```css
svg {
    border: 1px solid;
}
path{
    fill: lightsalmon;
    stroke: salmon;    
    stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3 Drawing</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/d3js/3.5.9/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Draw a polygon :D</h3>
```

Calculating the area should be quite simple since you have all the points!

Comment: Hello, 
Thank Jared this what I was looking for. 
Can we use this code freely on a web site ?

Comment: yep should be fine to use :)

Comment: @JaredGeilich Thanks for this answer. I'm new to d3. is it possible when a ploygon is drawn (let's say rectangle  shape), then I should be able to add more as many points to its border and when I start stretching one of the available points, it will start taking shape accordingly ? pls help you know it.